# How do i close database instance in gorm 1.20.0

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm, glide-golang

As i have not found in Close() function with *gorm instance, any help would be appreciated

```
dbURI := fmt.Sprintf("user=%s password=%s dbname=%s port=%s sslmode=%s TimeZone=%s",
    "username", "password", "dbname", "5432", "disable", "Asia/Kolkata")
fmt.Println(dbURI)
connection, err := gorm.Open(postgres.Open(dbURI), &gorm.Config{})

if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error connecting database")
    panic(err.Error())
} else {
    fmt.Println("Connected to database")
}
```

Note: connection.Close() is not available for GORM 1.20.0

Comment: May I ask why you want to close it?

Answer (score 27):

Jinzhu decided to eliminate the `Close()` method on version 1.20 because GORM supports connection pooling, so the correct use would be to open a connection and share it within your application.

If your specific use-case still requires to use the `Close()` method, GORM provides the method DB that returns a [db generic_interface](https://gorm.io/docs/generic_interface.html) where you can use it.

For the example

```
sqlDB, err := db.DB()

// Close
sqlDB.Close()
```

Comment: May that's the reason i have not found any Close() method with it

Answer (score 10):

I think you can use below codes to close your database connection:

```
sqlDB, err := connection.DB()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalln(err)
}
defer sqlDB.Close()
```

Comment: I Guess Close() is not available from 1.20.0

Comment: I do not close the connection, i close the connection.DB(), and i already assigned it to sqlDB

Comment: The 
defer sqlDB.Close() is the best way which enables us to close the connection once the whole code runs completely

Answer (score 3):

Gorm v2 provides a method to close the db connection.

Here is an example:

```
db, err := gorm.Open(sqlite.Open(dbFile), &gorm.Config{
    Logger: logger.Default.LogMode(logger.Silent),
})
if err != nil {
    t.Error(err)
}

defer func() {
    dbInstance, _ := db.DB()
    _ = dbInstance.Close()
}()
```